# siunitx error: "invalid-number"

Tags: siunitx

Very reduced example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
   n(O2)&=\SI{\frac{0,3}{2}}{\mol}\qquad\qquad &n(Fe3O4)&=\SI{0,3}{\mol} % <- this line
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However I end up with

```
siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"
n(O2)&=\SI{\frac{0,3}{2}}{\mol}
                               \qquad\qquad &n(Fe3O4)&=\SI{0,3}{\mol}
```

Any clue on what's my problem here?

Comment: I don't think you can use frac as an input number. You can probably ask it not to parse the number part in this case, consult the manual. Also you might want to look at the mhchem package to format the Fe3O4.

Comment: `\frac` is not a number as far as `siunitx`'s parsing goes. You can disable the parsing rules for that single instance using `parse-numbers=false`.

Comment: Using chemfig but removed it to be easier readable @daleif

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering:
Either use

```
\sisetup{parse-numbers = false}
```

(thanks to Skillmon)
or

```
\sisetup{quotient-mode = fraction}
```

and input the number as \SI{3/4}{\mol}.

Comment: You can also use this as an optional argument to `\SI` if you don't want to disable parsing globally (so `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\frac{0.3}{2}}{\mol}`).

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that `siunitx` means a number written in decimal notation and not fractional.

[image: siunitx]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
   n(O2)&=\SI{.15}{\mol}\qquad\qquad &n(Fe3O4)&=\SI{0.3}{\mol} % <- this line
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```